# Drupal 7: Webform: Send Email Custom PHP on Webform submit

Tags: webforms, emails

0 down vote favorite

I have a webform and I want to send an email to a user on submit action on this webform.

Note: I do not want to use the inbuild emails module for webform as it has some limitations related to the functionality that i want to achieve. Hence I want to send a test email on Submit action via a custom PHP.

I know how to write PHP for a webform but I need some guidance on how to use it for sending emails.

Also I want to send emails on submit action only if user selects a select option on this form.

How can I do this? Please help I am stuck on this for a long time now.

I tried using Rules module but I can not check the webform field values in rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you could use either [hook_webform_submission_presave](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7) or [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) in a custom module, check for the your webform component value (i'd assume it's in $submission) and then fire your email.

In a custom module, add your hook like so.

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_insert($node, &$submission){
  // Use devel to investigate the variable
  dsm($submission);
}
```

Creating custom modules for [Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) or [Drupal 6](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/6). [Tutorial](http://buildamodule.com/video/drupal-6-development-and-tools-essential-concepts-how-to-build-your-first-drupal-module#viewing).

Use [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module to investigate your variables, as seen in my example above.

Jason.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. Can you please tell me about how to add hooks? I am really new to drupal

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about module development. Good luck!